# Calculate Median Sales for each Customer in Array of Customers (Neophyte)

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, median

I have an array of customer objects generated from a csv file:

Date, Name, Sales
03/01, Alpha, 110
03/23, Alpha, 25
01/02, Beta, 135
...
and require an efficient way to create a new array of unique customers with median sales and export them back to csv. There could be as many as 500,000 records and 100,000 unique customers!

Answer (score 2):

-Split your source data into collections for each customer.

For each customer:

--Sort by sales

--if record count is odd, return the sales at the middle index

--if record count is even, return the avg of the records on either side of the middle

-Drop the returned record into your results array.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this I would use:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict;
```

The keys are the customer names (assuming they are unique, otherwise assign a unique ID of some sort?)
The values are lists of sales for each customer. After you have filled this array you may procceed in either sorting and getting the middle element (as mentioned above) <strike>or summing and dividing by the number of elements to get the median.</strike> (this is wrong)

Sorting (using a method which compares) takes O(nlog n) time where n is the length of the list to be sorted.

There are selection algorithms which can return the kth smallest value in O(n), check wikipedia link below

Comment: Summing the list and dividing by count is the average(mean). You won't  (always) get the same as the median.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median